# Analysing MP3 stream for Silence

Tags: python, mp3, icecast

I would like to detect silence from an icecast radio stream, i have attempted the following code, however when i silence the stream the rms value stays the same where i would expect a close to zero value: any help

Code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import audioop, numpy as np



url =  "http://localhost:8382/listen.mp3"
u = urlopen(url)
data = u.read(8192)

while data:
        data = u.read(8192)
        #rms = audioop.rms(data, 2) 
        d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
        numpy_rms = np.sqrt(sum(d*d)/len(d))
        print numpy_rms, audioop.rms(data, 2)
        #print rms
        print (min(d), max(d)), audioop.minmax(data,2)
```

alternate to analysing live stream, but not preferred option:
i have considered saving a 10 second mp3 files from the stream but not i am not sure how to analyse MP3. se code below

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from icerec.stream_writer import StreamWriter
from pprint import pprint

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Tool that will record a icecast stream.')

parser.add_argument('url', help="Icecast stream URL")
parser.add_argument('length', type=int, help="Length of time to record stream (in seconds)")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', default="./", 
                    help="File destination. Defaults to current directory")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', default="output.mp3", help="File name of saved stream")

args = parser.parse_args()

s = StreamWriter( args.url, args.length, destination=args.destination, filename=args.filename)

s.record()
pprint(s.metadata)
```

Comment: You should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526996/split-audio-files-using-silence-detection

Comment: Also `sox` is a tool that can do such things out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come up with this solution.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from icerec.stream_writer import StreamWriter
from pprint import pprint
import array
import httplib,urllib
from pydub.utils import get_array_type

from pydub.playback import play
from pydub.utils import mediainfo
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence
import numpy as np
import  audioop

poURL = 'api.pushover.net:443'
apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

#pushover_alert################################################################
def Notify(poApiKey, poUserKey, poTitle, poMessage, poPriority,poSound):
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(poURL)
        conn.request('POST', '/1/messages',
        urllib.urlencode({
        'token': poApiKey,
        'user': poUserKey,
        'token': poApiKey,
        'user': poUserKey,
        'title': poTitle,
        'message': poMessage,
        'priority': poPriority,
        'sound': poSound,
        }), { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })

while True:

        try:
                s = StreamWriter( "http://localhost:8382/listen.mp3", 0.5, destination="/var/www/html/", filename="output.mp3")
                s.record()
                #pprint(s.metadata)
                sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/var/www/html/output.mp3")


                bit_depth = sound.sample_width * 8
                array_type = get_array_type(bit_depth)
                numeric_array = array.array(array_type, sound._data)
                info = mediainfo("/var/www/html/output.mp3")
                #print numeric_array
                if sound.rms <10:
                        i += 1
                else:
                        i = 0

                if i  == 5:
                        mesg = 'Qkradio Stream Silence Detected for more than 5seconds'
                        print 'alert sent', mesg
                        Notify('xxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxx','Aquarium controller',mesg,0,'siren')
                print i ,"\tfile rms:", sound.rms,"\tfile loudness:", sound.dBFS, "\tPeak Amplitude:", sound.max,"\tlength:", len(sound),"\tSample rate:" ,info['sample_rate']
        except:
                print "error"
```